# rawurlencode() and urlencode() not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, urlencode

I am trying to encode a string into a safe url for generic purposes, and neither rawurlencode() nor urlencode() work when using CodeIgniter. I have used them and they work pefectly fine with straight PHP, but for whatever reason, it doesn't work. I haven't been able to find any others with this problem and thus no solution.

Code:

```
<a href="/search/degree/<?=rawurlencode($row->degree)?>" class="element_link"><?=$row->degree?></a>
```

It just gets passed as plain text with spaces unescaped and everything.

I was expecting the outcome I was able to get with this:

```
<?php echo rawurlencode('http://kchason.com'); ?>
```

Merited: http%3A%2F%2Fkchason.com

But: 
`<a href="/search/degree/<?=rawurlencode($row->degree)?>" class="element_link"><?=$row->degree?></a>`

Gives me for example: 'localhost/http://kchason.com' which obviously isn't safe and doesn't work.

Comment: Want to post a code sample so we can see what context this is happening in? both are built in php functions and CI does not interfere with straight PHP, so I would guess you're not passing it a string where you would notice a difference... without seeing the example, that is.

Comment: Please define "don't work". What is the output of the above snippet and what would you expect?

Comment: `rawurlencode('http://kchason.com')` correctly gives me `http%3A%2F%2Fkchason.com`. Your link is supposed to point to `/search/degree/...`, but your example says `localhost/...`. Are you sure you're looking at the right link?

Comment: Yes, I have done it properly in other capacities, but for some reason, with CI, it is no longer working.

Comment: Some reasons? just one: your code; somewhere in your code you're doing something not right, because CI or not, those are native php functions and CI is built USING php, it's not an alternative php interpreter with its own rules. Are you sure you're not calling it inside a CI's url helper?

Comment: I am aware that it is a PHP framework and thus should not affect the native PHP functions. In terms of your url helper comment, I have the url helper autoloaded but it is not called at this time. Does that have something to do with it?

Comment: Something else I found: `$website_link = rawurlencode($website);` merits the correct output and when I echo it in plain text it works. But when I try to use it in an anchor tag `<a href=/url/"<?=$website_link?>">$website</a>` It creates a link without the encoding.

Comment: We need a bit more context to see what is going on here. Can you provide us more of the code?  echo out `$row->degree` and `rawurlencode($row->degree)` by themselves and let us see the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old question. But I was dealing with the same issue. What I have done is:

**Encode**

```
<?php echo urlencode(base64_encode('http://kchason.com')); ?>
```

**Decode**

```
<?php echo urldecode(base64_decode('http://kchason.com')); ?>
```

You use `base64_encode` to get rid of any URL parts that will cause problems with Codeigniter, and then you use `urlencode` to encode any `=` that `base64_encode` adds to the end of its output.

Comment: `base64_encode` still creates `==` at the end of some strings and `urlencode` swaps it with `%3D%3D` which contains `%`, a problematic CI character. So I don't think this is the correct answer.